# Ruby Mechanize submit buttons not working correctly

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have been working on a Ruby Script that enters in data into a search field and then needs to click on the enter button. By looking at the "pp" my data is correctly inputing into the search field. The problem I am having is clicking on the "enter" button. What is happening is that it is not moving forward it is just refreshing the current screen. When I manually access the website in question via IE, enter the search data and hit enter on my keyboard it doesn't roll to the search screen; I have to click with the mouse on enter to get it to move forward. If I use Chrome and preform the same task with the keyboard enter then it opens a new tab. How do I get this programmatically to move forward?

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
page = agent.get('https://somewebsite.com')

check_form = page.form
check_form['ct100$MainContent$txtNumber'] = 'J520518'

pp page

page = agent.submit(check_form, check_form.buttons.first)

pp page

page.links.each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```

Here is snippit from the output:

```
...
<forms
#<Mechanize::Form
<name nil>
<method "POST">
<action "">
<fields
...
[field:0xb627a0 type: name:ct100$MainContent$txtNumber value: J520518]>
...
<buttons
[submit:0xb6d8ac type: submit name: ct100$MainContent$btnEnter value: Enter]
}>}>
...
<forms
#<Mechanize::Form
<name nil>
<method "POST">
<action "">
<fields
...
[field:0xb627a0 type: name:ct100$MainContent$txtNumber value: ]>
...
<buttons
[submit:0xb6d8ac type: submit name: ct100$MainContent$btnEnter value: Enter]
```

As always, thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to parse using **watir** since I am using IE. Then I was able to use **nokogiri** to parse the last page. Ultimately, I was on the right track with the code above, but **Mechanize** is not able to handle JavaScript at this time. Since watir is a driver for the brower rather than acting like it's own browser it is able to handle the JavaScript. I hope this helps anyone that lands on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net websites like this are a challenge to scrape because of the javascript callbacks on everything. You can generally preserve your sanity by using selenium or a js-aware environment like node.js

Comment: I have never used either of those products. Would they allow me to enter a file where each line item needs to be searched? Let me explain what it is I am doing. I have a file with ~30K lines of data that needs to be searched. For each item I am looking for specific keywords in the results. If the results meet my criteria need to output to a file. I know how to do that with RUBY, but as you can see I am having some headache from this particular website. I am not against learning a new product if I know that I can get the end file that I need for my employer. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing but I recommend watir::webdriver, it's the easiest way to navigate this site with ruby.

Comment: Thank you...I am switching to watir!